# How to remove next pandas dataframe row when it's equal to previous row only for some columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, drop

I have created a dataframe called `df` with this code:

```
# initialize list of lists
data = {'ID': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7],
        'feature1': [100,32,100,100,100,93,100],
        'feature2': [100,32,100,100,100,93,100],
        'feature3': [100,32,100,100,100,93,100],
        }
 
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
print(df)

   ID  feature1  feature2  feature3
0   1       100       100       100
1   2        32        32        32
2   3       100       100       100
3   4       100       100       100
4   5       100       100       100
5   6        93        93        93
6   7       100       100       100
```

I want to remove the rows in which the values of columns:

- `feature1` **and**
- `feature2` **and**
- `feature3`
  are exactly the same as the **previous** row. In the example above, I need to remove rows `3` and `4`, so that the resulting dataframe will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Filter` the `feature` like columns then calculate difference between previous and current row and check whether the difference is `0` for all the `feature` columns

```
df[~df.filter(like='feature').diff().eq(0).all(1)]
```

---

```
   ID  feature1  feature2  feature3
0   1       100       100       100
1   2        32        32        32
2   3       100       100       100
5   6        93        93        93
6   7       100       100       100
```

Comment: thanks. Quick question. What if the columns to compare have different name. For example:
- feature1
- column2
- field3

?

Comment: @GiampaoloLevorato In that case you can explicitly select the required columns. Please check: `df[~df[['col1', 'col2', 'field3']].diff().eq(0).all(1)]`